# Weird bookmarks with random string reference in InDesign generated PDF?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a document in InDesign with some headings and a table of contents generated from them. In the exported PDF file I get lots of bookmarks with weird names starting with "h", followed by period, then a random string of varied length (11-13 characters from my experience), for example: "h.f3wy1wqelkasj".

I was thinking this had to do with the table of contents, but no. There are bookmarks from heading levels not in the table of contents. And the only exists in the last chapter of the document. Everything is in the same document.

What can I do to remove these unwanted bookmarks?

When I go into the story editor I notice a weird symbol I have not seen before.

[image: bookmark symbol?]

Answer (score 2):

As it turned out, I could just edit them away in the story editor. They are hyperlinks anchors. Still, I have no idea how the got there.

Comment: A Word import perhaps?

Comment: No but a similar program perhaps. I don't remember the origin of all the different chapters.

Comment: Thanks to this answer, I figured out that the junk bookmarks also show up in the "bookmarks" panel (Windows>Interactive>bookmarks). So you can select all or many of these (Shift-select) and trash them. That's way less tedious than the story editor route.